# Контекстное меню в QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2, qtablewidget, contextmenu

В *GUI* при нажатии правой кнопкой мыши на таблицу, вызывается **`контекстное меню`**. Но проблема, что после этого это контекстное меню можно вызвать не только в таблице, но и в любом месте окна приложения за пределами таблицы `QTableWidget`.

Как это исправить? 
Мне нужно вызывать конкретное меню на конкретной таблице. И нигде больше.

Привожу простой пример *GUI*, где ошибка четко воспроизводится:

**app.py**

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from UI_test import Ui_Form
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class App(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    def contextMenuEvent(self,e):
        #создание и вызов контекстного меню
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self)
        Action1 = QtWidgets.QAction('Action1', self)
        Action2 = QtWidgets.QAction('Action2', self)
        Action3 = QtWidgets.QAction('Action3', self)
        self.menu.addAction(Action1)
        self.menu.addAction(Action2)
        self.menu.addAction(Action3)
        self.menu.popup(QtGui.QCursor.pos())



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = App()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**UI_test.py**

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
from random import randint

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.resize(1300, 700)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.listWidget.currentRowChanged.connect(
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex)

        item1 = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(QtGui.QIcon('icons/settings.png'),'CamSettings', self.listWidget)
        item2 = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(QtGui.QIcon('icons/explore.png'),'Explore', self.listWidget)

        item1.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(10, 60))
        item2.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(10, 60))

        item1.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        item2.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Это страница 1')
        label2= QtWidgets.QLabel('Это страница 2')
        label1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        label2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        label1.setStyleSheet('background: rgb(%d, %d, %d); margin: 50px;' % (
        randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255)))
        label2.setStyleSheet('background: rgb(%d, %d, %d); margin: 50px;' % (
        randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255)))

        self.table_cubes = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.table_cubes.setColumnCount(1)
        self.table_cubes.setObjectName('tableCubes')
        self.table_cubes.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Название куба'])
        header_class = self.table_cubes.horizontalHeader()
        header_class.hide()
        header_v_cube = self.table_cubes.verticalHeader()
        header_v_cube.setStyleSheet(' background-color: #232939;')
        self.table_cubes.setFixedWidth(310)
        self.table_cubes.setFixedHeight(330)
        self.table_cubes.setColumnWidth(0, 200)
        self.table_cubes.contextMenuEvent = Form.contextMenuEvent
        first_panel_left = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        first_panel_left.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        first_panel_frame_left = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        first_panel_frame_left.setMinimumWidth(200)
        first_panel_frame_left.setLayout(first_panel_left)
        first_panel_right = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        first_panel_right.addWidget(self.table_cubes)
        first_panel_right.addStretch()
        first_panel_frame_right = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        first_panel_frame_right.setLayout(first_panel_right)
        main_first_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        main_first_box.addWidget(first_panel_frame_left)
        main_first_box.addWidget(first_panel_frame_right)
        first_container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        first_container.setLayout(main_first_box)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(first_container)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(label2)
        Form.setLayout(self.layout)
```

Comment: `self.table_cubes.contextMenuEvent = Form.contextMenuEvent` перепиши`self.table_cubes.contextMenuEvent = Form.onContextMenuEvent` и реализуй метод onContextMenuEvent

Comment: Благодарю,помогло!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант

```
import sys
from random import randint
'''
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
'''
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#from UI_test import Ui_Form
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.resize(800, 500)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.listWidget.currentRowChanged.connect(
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex)

        item1 = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(QtGui.QIcon('Ok.png'),'CamSettings', self.listWidget)
        item2 = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(QtGui.QIcon('im.png'),'Explore', self.listWidget)

        item1.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(10, 60))
        item2.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(10, 60))

        item1.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        item2.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Это страница 1')
        label2= QtWidgets.QLabel('Это страница 2')
        label1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        label2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        label1.setStyleSheet('background: rgb(%d, %d, %d); margin: 50px;' % (
        randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255)))
        label2.setStyleSheet('background: rgb(%d, %d, %d); margin: 50px;' % (
        randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255)))

        self.table_cubes = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.table_cubes.setColumnCount(1)
        self.table_cubes.setObjectName('tableCubes')
        self.table_cubes.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Название куба'])
        header_class = self.table_cubes.horizontalHeader()
        header_class.hide()
        header_v_cube = self.table_cubes.verticalHeader()
        header_v_cube.setStyleSheet(' background-color: #232939;')
        self.table_cubes.setFixedWidth(310)
        self.table_cubes.setFixedHeight(330)
        self.table_cubes.setColumnWidth(0, 200)
# -       self.table_cubes.contextMenuEvent = Form.contextMenuEvent
        
        first_panel_left = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        first_panel_left.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        first_panel_frame_left = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        first_panel_frame_left.setMinimumWidth(200)
        first_panel_frame_left.setLayout(first_panel_left)
        first_panel_right = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        first_panel_right.addWidget(self.table_cubes)
        first_panel_right.addStretch()
        first_panel_frame_right = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        first_panel_frame_right.setLayout(first_panel_right)
        main_first_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        main_first_box.addWidget(first_panel_frame_left)
        main_first_box.addWidget(first_panel_frame_right)
        first_container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        first_container.setLayout(main_first_box)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(first_container)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(label2)
        Form.setLayout(self.layout)
        
        
class App(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        self.item = None
        self.ui.table_cubes.installEventFilter(self)                             # !!! 
        self.ui.table_cubes.setRowCount(3) 
        self.ui.table_cubes.setItem(0, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('Hello'))        
        self.ui.table_cubes.setItem(2, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('World'))          

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.ContextMenu and source is self.ui.table_cubes:
            menu = QMenu()
            menu.addAction('Action 1')
            menu.addAction('Action 2')
            menu.addAction('Action 3')

            menu.triggered.connect(self.selected)                               
                    
            if menu.exec_(event.globalPos()):
                self.item = source.itemAt(event.pos())
            return True
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)
        
    def selected(self, q):
        self.q = q.text()
        QTimer.singleShot(10, lambda: print(f'{self.item.text() if self.item else None}: {self.q}'))
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = App()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]